# PageSpeedInsights API V5 Return Overall Speed Score

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I've tried using V4, which returns a metric ruleGroups" looking like this:

```
{
  "SPEED": {
   "score": 10
```

In V5, it seems that this metric is omitted, is there a way to include it?

Note: It should return [image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its there. Check results carefully.

```json
"lighthouseResult" :{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    "categories" : {
        "performance": {
            "score" : 1,
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: image.png]